# DataTables pagination doesn't seem to work with server side data

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I do not understand why this pagination doesn't working:

```
 jQuery(function($) {
    $('#lista-contatti').DataTable({

        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
         //"info": true,
        "ajax": {
            url: "/test/ajax_datatable.cfm",
            cache:  false,
        },

        "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "ute_nominativo" },
                { "data": "ute_email" },
                { "data": "ute_data" },
                { "data": "ute_ip" },
                { "data": "ute_lista"},
                { "data": "azioni" }
        ]

        });
});
```

It **works only the first page**, but do not load the next pages. I'm still missing something…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server-side script should return `draw` parameter with the same value of the `draw` parameter in the request. Right now you're always returning `1`.

From the [manual](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data):

> `draw`
>
> The draw counter that this object is a response to - from the `draw` parameter sent as part of the data request. Note that it is **strongly recommended for security reasons** that you cast this parameter to an integer, rather than simply echoing back to the client what it sent in the `draw` parameter, in order to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: i am getting same issue but  after commenting "serverSide": true, my code  works .

Comment: @Haseeb Thanks dude i just comment serSide it's worked